# tab order is not working in Cell editing Kendo UI Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, tab-ordering

I am using Kendo UI Grid.And i want to do InCell editing on it.The InCell editing is working well.And once i click on "Add New Record" button then it shows textbox for the first column "Name".

My problem is when i press tab after putting value on "Name" field then its not shifting into second field "Description".And the tab order should work there.

Below is the piece of code for Kendo Grid :-

```
@using Gts.GlaspacLX.Web.App_Start;
@using Gts.GlaspacLX.ListValues;
@using System.Collections;
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@*<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.min.js")"></script>*@
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/js/Product/Category.js"></script>
<style>
.k-dirty { display:none; }
</style>


<fieldset>
    <form>           
        <div id="divProduct" style="display: none;">


@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Gts.GlaspacLX.Web.ViewModel.ProductViewModel>()
    .Name("ProductGrid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Width(200);                                                       
        columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy(); }).Width(75);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Hidden();
    })
    .ToolBar(commands => {
        commands.Create();
        commands.Save();
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Model(model => {
            model.Id(p => p.ID);
        })                                           
        .Read(read => read.Action("ProductEditingInline_Read", "Product"))
        .Create(create => create.Action("ProductEditingInline_Create", "Product"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("ProductEditingInline_Update", "Product"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("ProductEditingInline_Destroy", "Product")
        )
       .Events(events => events.Change("onProductChange"))
       // .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    )
)


            <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick=" $('.k-button.k-button-icontext.k-grid-cancel-changes').click(); $('#productWindow').data('kendoWindow').close(); " />
            <input type="button" value="Save" onclick=" SaveProductChanges(); " />
        </div>
    </form>
</fieldset>
}
```

Can anyone help me out on this ?

Comment: Why is your grid wrapped inside a `form` inside a `fieldset`?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use the [navigatable option](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/grid/walkthrough#keyboard-navigation) of the grid.  Following is a jsfiddle example I've built:  [Kendo Grid Example with keyboard navigation](http://jsfiddle.net/Rick_Mortensen/Wtrb4/1/).  In MVC the navigatable option is turned on by calling .Navigatable() on the grid (see example below):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TestModel>()
.Name("TestGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bind(c => c.DisabledString);
    columns.Bind(c => c.Description);
    columns.Bind(c => c.TestInvisibleDate);
    columns.Bind(c => c.TestDate);
    columns.Bind(c => c.AllExpressions);
})
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.Sortable()
.Scrollable(s => { s.Enabled(true); s.Virtual(true); })
.Pageable(p => p.Enabled(false))
.Mobile(MobileMode.Disabled)
.Navigatable()
.Resizable(s => s.Columns(true))
.Reorderable(c => c.Columns(true))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Batch(true)
    .PageSize(50)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(e => e.UniqueId);
    })
    )
)
```

This help?